# How to have powershell use a else statement to search another folder

Tags: powershell, if-statement, outlook, pst

I am trying to import some PST files into Outlook automatically, I currently am using the following script

```
Add-type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook" | out-null 
$outlook = new-object -comobject outlook.application 
$namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI") 
dir “$env:USERPROFILE\appdata\local\microsoft\outlook\.pst” | % { 
$namespace.AddStore($_.FullName) }
```

I would like to add a else statement so that if the pst file is not found in the first location then it will check in "$env:USERPROFILE\Documents\Outlook Files"

Comment: Do you mean "*.pst" rather than just ".pst" in the `dir` command?

Comment: `“` and `”` may also cause issues (in the line with your path). Use `"`, like in your first line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a single file, use `Test-Path` to verify if the file is in the location you expect, for example:

```
$pathA = "C:\path\to\my\file"
$pathB = "C:\path\to\another\file"

if(Test-Path $pathA){
  # do something with $pathA
}
else {
  # do something with $pathB
}
```

In your case you are using `dir` (an alias for `Get-ChildItem`) which returns all files in a folder matching the path/name specified. What you may want to do is to look for the files first in PathA and, if you don't find any, look in PathB:

```
$pathA = "C:\path\to\my\folder\*.pst"
$pathB = "C:\path\to\another\folder\*.pst"

$files = Get-ChildItem $pathA

if($files){
  # do something with $pathA
}
else {
  # do something with $pathB
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone curious here is my new final script

```
    $pathA = “$env:USERPROFILE\AppData\Local\Microsoft\*.pst”
    $pathB = “$env:USERPROFILE\Documents\Outlook Files\*.pst”

    $files = Get-ChildItem $pathA

    Add-type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook" | out-null 
    $outlook = new-object -comobject outlook.application 
    $namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI") 

    if($files){
    dir “$env:USERPROFILE\AppData\Local\Microsoft\*.pst” | % {                                 
    $namespace.AddStore($_.FullName) }
    }
    else {
    dir “$env:USERPROFILE\Documents\Outlook Files\*.pst” | % {                         
    $namespace.AddStore($_.FullName) }
    }
```

Thanks again Charlie, That was a great help!

Comment: You can move the first 3 identical lines of code from within the `if(){...} else {...}` blocks to just before the `if` statement begins, since you'll be running those 3 lines regardless. It's good practice to keep code repetition to a minimum.

Comment: Yes. That looks OK to me. You'll probably find as many different ways to write code to do what you want as programmers you ask, but I'd say that most would agree on reducing duplicate lines of code when the logic branches one way or another.